# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRowData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am using with Angular 1.x with ag-grid. first of all I am confused how I do activate enterprise feature. I am evaluating now we are planing to buy the enterprise but support is pretty weak.

Now the actual problem I am trying to feed the data from ElasticSearch to the grid. I am trying to simulate like demo of ag-grid. If change the pagesize it will retrieve the data from ES server and feed the grid with new datasets with new pagesize. For that I am using $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(data) on any action if I try to update the grid I mean setRowData. I am getting error "method is undefined" It works for the first time when it loads the page.

How do I resolve this issue? Am I missing anything?

Function: This is the function where I invoking the $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(data) and I am getting error

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRowData' of undefined"

```
function displayGrid(fromDate, toDate, fieldNameArray, affiliate, product,consmb, region, customer, page, pageSize)
  {

   // Constructing Query from dashboard input
        var gridQuery = globalFiltersDrillDown(fromDate, toDate, fieldNameArray, page, pageSize);
        var finalGridQuery = buildQueryForDrillQuery(affiliate,product, consmb, region, customer, gridQuery, "" , false);
        console.log("final Query :" + JSON.stringify(finalGridQuery));
       var data =[];

    setTimeout(function ()
    {
       esClientIndirect.search
          (
            {
              index: esIndex1,
              type: esType1,
              size : pageSize,
              from : page,
              body: finalGridQuery
            },
            function (error, response, status)
            {
              $scope.numberOfRecords = numberCommas(response.hits.total);
              if(error)
              {
                $scope.error = "Error : " + status ;
              }
              else
              {
                var startBrace = "{ ";
                var endBrace = " }"
                data.length = 0;
                var k = 0;
                for(var o in response.hits.hits)
                {
                  var dataFields = response.hits.hits[o].fields;
                  var numberOfElements = fieldNameArray.length -1;
                  var row = startBrace;
                  for (var i in dataFields)
                  {
                    var columnName = fieldNameArray[k];
                    var columnValue =  dataFields[columnName];
                    if (k == numberOfElements)
                    {
                      row += (" \"" + columnName +"\" : \"" + columnValue +"\"");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      row += (" \"" + columnName +"\" : \"" + columnValue +"\",");
                    }
                    k = k+1;
                  }
                  row += endBrace;
                  k =0;
                  data.push(JSON.parse(row));
                }
                // pushing data into the ag-grid
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                  $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
                }, 200);
            }
            }, 100); // end of elastic search call back
            }); // end of elastic search set time out call back
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the api doesn't exist. Have you made sure that you have instantiated $scope.gridOptions before you do this call?

Comment: how come its working for the first time when the page loads for the first time?